# What is the best way to pass data from one cli app to another

Tags: php, ruby, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

For example how to pass data from one cli application for example Ruby script to PHP script. I mean raw data, text, binary and etc.. Arguments falls out because of raw data using temp files also is kind lame. The last thing I know which would work is stdin, stdout. Maybe someone knows anything better?

Comment: xml is generally used to communicate among different applications.

Comment: He didn't ask what format to use, he asked how to send the data between programs. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you on? That determines what is available to you somewhat. You should use what is common for the platform. On *nix systems we use pipes (`|`), sockets and data files, depending on the application.

There's really no one way of doing it, it just depends on the type of application, and the type of data.

If you are moving columns of text or CSV data you could use pipes or text files.

If you are moving hashes and objects between Ruby apps, use JSON or "Marshall" the data and a pipe, socket or a file.

If you are moving data between languages, use JSON, XML or YAML and one of those data paths.

We regularly use JSON for our inter-application data format, and write our code to allow it to emit JSON when we set a command-line flag. That allows us to easily wrap command-line apps with a little REST service and call them remotely, throwing their results around the web.

All that said, there isn't a hard and fast rule saying how anything is done, just be consistent with your code and follow the style of the apps you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the how those programs are executed (in relation to one another). If one stops and start the other, stdin/out or even dumping a file might do the trick (although it may be considered lame, it does the job!), if there is a lot of data you might even consider creating a small database table in a database like SQLite or something. That also depends on the requirements how volatile the data passed between the data might be.

If there is a parent/child process relation, so the parent starts a child process, you might consider a pipe/fifo, or shared memory or a message queue or any other form of IPC.